# MongoDB Aggregation sum the results

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework

Are there some good examples where I want to aggregate the following using Mongo's Aggregation Pipeline in scala.

Want to get the sum `PriceAmt`.

Any good URL with some great Scala examples would be of great help..
Following is the JSON that is being retrieved from MongoDB.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5269723bd516ec3a69f3639e"),
  "Id": ObjectId("5269723ad516ec3a69f3639d"),
  "results": [
    {
      "Id": "526971f5b5b8b9148404623a",
      "pricingResult": {
        "TxId": 0,
        "PriceId": "Large_Batch_1",
        "Errors": [ ],
        "Disposition": [
          {
            "GroupId": 1,
            "PriceAmt": 20,
            "Status": "Priced Successfully",
            "ReasonCode": 0,
            "PricingMethodologyId": 2,
            "Lines": [{ "Id": 1 }]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ClaimId": "526971f4b5b8b91484046229",
      "pricingResult": {
        "TxId": 0,
        "PriceId": "Large_Batch_1",
        "Errors": [ ],
        "Disposition": [
          {
            "GroupId": 1,
            "PriceAmt": 20,
            "Status": "Priced Successfully",
            "ReasonCode": 0,
            "PricingMethodologyId": 2,
            "Lines": [{ "Id": 1 }]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is a valid question, but if you are looking for examples of aggregation framework and scala take a look at this links:

- https://bhudgeons.telegr.am/blog_posts/how-to-use-the-new-mongodb-aggregation-framew
- http://mongoblog.tumblr.com/post/44108207769/mongodb-aggregation-using-scala-1-2

and after this you can try to replicate some results with scala using [examples from mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/)

Answer (score 0):

Casbah, the official Scala driver, support the aggregation framework.

Please take a look at the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/guide/aggregation.html).